# Java collections brain teasers

Tags: java, collections

Java collections are invaluable tool in exchanging data between database and service layer. We have various cases of a HashMap, ArrayList, a HashMap of arraylists etc.

I'm looking for programming samples, that contain a lot of exercise from simple to complex to deal with collections. It need not have answers/sample codes, just a variety of difficult questions would be enough.

Anyone know of any such website?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure this is very complex (it's meant to serve as interview questions), but it's a decent collection of questions on collections (I've used it in the past when interviewing people for developers positions).. :
http://www.interview-questions-java.com/java-collections.htm .

Answer (score 2):

[Official Java Collections Tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/collections/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

### The Official Guides

- [The Java Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/)'s [Collections trail](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/index.html) (written by J. Bloch)
- [The Java SE Collections-Related APIs and Developer Guides](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/collections/index.html)

### Books

- [Effective Java](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/effective/) (by J. Bloch too!) contains a few nuggets that relate to Collections.
- [Discursive](http://www.discursive.com)'s [Common Java Cookbook](http://www.discursive.com/books/cjcook/reference/collections.html) contains some interesting examples. Though some use 3rd party libraries, they still capture the essence of waht you can do with Collections and how they are implemented.

### Others

- [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/)'s "[collections"-tagged questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/collections)
- [Project Euler](http://projecteuler.net/) (the problems often involve the use of data-structures, so doing this type of exercises will force you to get to know them pretty well)

Answer (score 0):

[The Java Developers Almanac](http://www.exampledepot.com/).

Answer (score 0):

[Java Data Structures](http://www.theparticle.com/javadata2.html)

Answer (score 0):

Although Bloch`s Effective Java treats Java Collections, it is not as thorough as [Java Generics and Collections](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596527756). If you can combine them, all the better.